# Unserialize error for libraries/Extensions.php after EE upgrade from 2.5.2 to 2.5.5

Tags: error, upgrade, ee2-upgrades, php-errors

I've tried upgrading EE from 2.5.2 to 2.5.5. The upgrade apparently went through OK, but when I login to the CP - none of the menu items are clickable and also the rounded borders on the menu items don't display.

I'm also getting an error when CP tries to load the following as a script;

```
admin.php?S=0&amp;D=cp&amp;C=javascript&amp;M=load&amp;file=css&amp;theme=default&amp;v=1356028154
```

When I check the Sources tab in Chrome Developer tool, I see the following;

```
<div style="border:1px solid #990000;padding-left:20px;margin:0 0 10px 0;">

<h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>

<p>Severity: Notice</p>
<p>Message:  unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 88 bytes</p>
<p>Filename: libraries/Extensions.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 229</p>

</div>(function($, doc) {var adv_css = {".button a,\n.cp_button a,\n#search form,\ndiv.contentMenu,\n#mainContent .formArea,\n#navigationTabs .first_level:not(.addTab)":{"border-radius":"10px"},"#navigationTabs .addTab":{"border-radius":"none"},"#accessoryTabs li,\n.heading":{"overflow":"hidden","border-top-right-radius":"10px","border-top-left-radius":"10px"},".tableFooter,\ndiv.pageContents,\n#mainContent #publishForm":{"border-bottom-right-radius":"10px","border-bottom-left-radius":"10px"},".newTemplate":{"border-radius":"5px"},"#write_mode_writer":{"border-radius":"15px"},".js_hide":{"display":"none"}}, selector, compat_el = doc.createElement("ee_compat"),supported = false,inline_css = [],use = ["", "", "$1$3"],prefixes = " webkit o ms moz Moz".split(" "),corners = " -top-right -top-left -bottom-right -bottom-left".split(" "),regex = /^-(.)(.*?)-(.)(.*)/,css_radii = {};$.each(prefixes, function(i) {var name = i ? this+"BorderRadius" : "borderRadius";if (compat_el.style[name] !== undefined) {if (i == 0) {use = ["border", "-radius", ""];}else if (i < 3) {use = ["-"+this+"-border", "-radius", ""];}else {use = ["-moz-border-radius", "", "-$1$2$3$4"];}supported = true;return false;}});$.each(corners, function(i, v) {if (use[2]) {v = v.replace(regex, use[2]);}css_radii["border"+this+"-radius"] = use[0]+v+use[1];});function process_css(key, value) {if (key.indexOf("@") == -1) {var apply_radius = "",sep = (supported) ? ":" : " ",jQel;for (radius in css_radii) {if (value[radius]) {apply_radius += css_radii[radius]+sep+value[radius]+";";delete(value[radius]);}}if (supported) {inline_css.push(key+"{"+apply_radius+"}");}else {jQel = $(key).css(value);if (apply_radius) {}}}else if (key.indexOf("@"+EE.router_class) != -1) {$.each(value, process_css);}}if (supported) {$.each(adv_css, process_css);var head = doc.getElementsByTagName("head")[0],ss_txt = doc.createTextNode(inline_css.join("\n")),ss_el = doc.createElement("style");ss_el.setAttribute("type", "text/css");ss_el.appendChild(ss_txt);head.appendChild(ss_el);}else {$(doc).ready(function() {$.each(adv_css, process_css);});}})(jQuery, this.document)
```

Wondered if anyone else had this issue? :/

Comment: Did you upload the 2.5.5 **javascript** and **cp_themes** folders (both found in **/themes**)?

Comment: Hey Derek, yes those folders are in the /themes folder. I think the issue might be the admin.php like that shoes '&amp;' instead of '&' ?

Comment: THose folders are there, but are they from the 2.5.5 download? Did you replace them during the upgrade?

Comment: Yep, they're from the 2.5.5 download and replaced during upgrade. I can see all of the jQuery UI scripts in /themes/javascript/compressed/jquery/ui/ :/

Answer (score 0):

An unserialise error with extensions probably means extension settings. Try disabling each extension one by one (backup first)